# Unable to open Qt form (*.ui) files from Visual Studio 

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, qt-designer

I am unable to open QT form file (*.ui) from a Visual Studio 2008 Qt project. I'm using Qt 4.5.0. I get the the following error:

```
The file test.ui cannot be opened with Qt 4 form editor. Try converting the file using uic.exe
```

Comment: Can you open it with Qt Designer?

Comment: FYI, it's written as Qt, not QT.

Comment: Paul: I am able to open and edit it using Qt Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same symptoms, and the solution was to remove the top line of the ui file (once open with a text editor)

Surprising that Qt does not support well formed xml...

Meilleures Salutations

Comment: thanks for the tip ! I haven't met this case ... Can you add some details about the line removed ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your *.ui file are in the qt4 format and not in the qt3 format ?
If there have been created with qt3, ui.exe can convert them to qt4 !

Another reason could be the version of the qt-integration tool for visual studio 2008, Do you have the last version ?
Can you open the *-ui file with Qt Designer ?

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. "<ui version="4.0">" present in *.ui file,i guess it is generated using Qt4

Answer (score 0):

Bingo! It worked, Thanks Antoine

Matthieu: remove the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>