# Converting Qt 3.x forms to Qt 4.x forms

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, qt4

I have Qt ui forms that were written in Qt3 and I would like to update them to be integrated in a Qt4 project.  When I open them in Qt Designer, the program gives a message: "This file was created using Designer from Qt-3.3 and will be converted to a new form by Qt Designer.  The old form has not been touched, but you will have to save the form under a new name."

Naturally, I save the files with new names.  I then delete the originals and rename the converted files to the same name after I've closed Qt Designer.  When I open VS2008 after cleaning the directory and running qmake, the ui files appear in the project but when I try to open them, I get the error: "The file cannot be opened with the Qt 4 form editor.  Try converting the file using uic.exe"

It should be noted that after saving the files in Qt Designer (and rename) the files open properly in Qt Designer without any warnings.  Proceding with the uic.exe, I'm lead to this page in my research: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qt3to4.html

I attempt to run the command: "uic3 -convert myform3.ui > myform4.ui" as was suggested by the Qt 3 to 4 guide (file names changed, of course).  The file generated is empty.

To Summarize:

I have attempted a simple re-saving with Qt Designer.

I have attempted to run uic3.exe

I have attempted to delete the first line of the file, suggested here: [Unable to open Qt form (*.ui) files from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109300/unable-to-open-qt-form-ui-files-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you use the Visual Studio with Qt 4.6.4 command prompt.  You can do this by loading the link from your Qt install, or by running this command first:

```
C:\Qt\4.6.4\bin\qtvars.bat vsvars
```

Then you'll be able to run `uic3` from your command prompt.